# Casting string to date in VB.NET

Tags: c#, sql, vb.net, visual-studio-2008

I am passing a date field to an SQL database.

The field is declared as `String` in the VB.NET application.

I wrote a piece of code for casting to `Date`:

```
Dim dtBdate As Date
If param_strDOB <> String.Empty Then
    dtBdate = Convert.ToDateTime(param_strDOB)
End If
```

But the value is passed as `#3/11/2011#`. It has a `#` - sign on either side of the Date Field.

How do I fix it?

In the SQL database the stored procedure takes the input parameter as " @DOB DateTime ".

Comment: Are you saying that `param_strDOB` is `#3/11/2011#`? If so, have you tried simply removing those hash characters?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1k1skd40.aspx):

> The date and time can be bracketed
>   with a pair of leading and trailing
>   NUMBER SIGN characters '#'

So you should be able to convert/parse as-is.

Answer (score 0):

Where are you seeing the `#`s? While looking at it in Visual Studio? If so, then it's just the debugger showing that it's a `Date` value. Just ignore them.

[Quote](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3eaydw6e%28VS.80%29.aspx):

> However, the compiler treats literals enclosed within number signs (# #) as Date.